# How to set dynamic parameters in c# methods

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parameters, event-handling

I have written a method `trial` for button `btnTrial1`:

```
public void trial(object sender, EventArgs e, Button btn, TextBox txt, Label lbl)
{

}
```

In my application, i am generating more buttons and textboxes and labels dynamically through code and naming them sequentially like `btnTrial2`, `txtTrial2`, `lblTrial2` then `btnTrial3`, `txtTrial3`, `lblTrial3` and so on. Now i want to set `trial` as EventHandler for `btnTrial2` then for `btnTrial3` and so on.

So now when i call the method `trial` from `btnTrial1`, my parameters should be:

```
Public void (sender, e, btnTrail1, txtTrial1, lblTrial1)
```

But when i call the method `trial` from `btnTrial2`, my parameters should be:

```
Public void (sender, e, btnTrail2, txtTrial2, lblTrial2)
```

and so on...

Comment: You really should be using the `EventHandler<T>` type for your events and not creating other delegates.  You should create a class which derives from `EventArgs` which holds your arguments.

Comment: exactly u got me right. i am trying to use it as a eventhandler and getting error Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'. And sorry for providing full information about my problem, but i am new to the programming field so do not know what all information should i put. sorry again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
btnTrial1.YourEvent += (sender, args) => trial(sender, args,
        btnTrial1, txtTrial1, lblTrial1);
btnTrial2.YourEvent += (sender, args) => trial(sender, args,
        btnTrial2, txtTrial2, lblTrial2);
```

You mention "generating them dynamically" - that is fine, but if you are in a loop you will also need to watch out for the infamous "captured variable / loop" problem - notably, the variables "captured" ***must*** be inside the loop; for example:

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++) {
    var btnTrial = ...
    var txtTrial = ...
    var lblTrial = ...
    btnTrial.YourEvent += (sender, args) => trial(sender, args,
        btnTrial, txtTrial, lblTrial);
}
```

(if, for example, `btnTrial` was declared *outside* the loop, bad things would happen)

Comment: +1 Yep, in this case solution should be simple and not overcomplicated

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your trial function

```
public void trial(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

And then based on the sender, use different controls:

```
public void trial(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn;
    TextBox txt;
    Label lbl;

    if (sender == btnTrial1){
        btn = btnTrail1;
        txt = txtTrial1;
        lbl = lblTrial1;
    }

    if (sender == btnTrial2){
        btn = btnTrail2;
        txt = txtTrial2;
        lbl = lblTrial2;
    }

    if (sender == btnTrial3){
        btn = btnTrail3;
        txt = txtTrial3;
        lbl = lblTrial3;
    }

    //rest of the method
}
```

Comment: interesting, but there is a problem. In my application, a user can make any number of controls, so is it advisable to keep on comparing values?

Answer (score 0):

To each button You can add:

```
this.button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
```

method like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String name = (sender as Control).Name;
    int number = Int32.Parse(name.Substring(name.Length-1));
    trial(sender, e, this.Controls["btnTrial"+number], this.Controls["txtTrial"+number], Controls["lblTrial"+number]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Refactor `trial()` to return an `EventHandler` (or ideally `EventHandler<T>`):

   ```
   public EventHandler GetTrialEventHandler(Button btn, TextBox txt, Label lbl)
   {
        return (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Do something with btn, txt, lbl
        };
   }
   ```
2. Rather than name your form elements `btnTrial1`, `btnTrial2`, etc, why not just make lists of the elements (or a list of sets of `Button`+`TextBox`+`Label`)? Then you just have to enumerate over the list(s) to set up your event handlers, rather than hard-code for each.

Comment: i tried doing it, but a i am able to give the list as parameter for my Eventhandler